# Is there another any alternative to torch.Generator() to support MPS device type? (M1 Mac, PyTorch)

Tags: python, pytorch, apple-m1

I am running python code for implementing stable diffusion on my m1 mac and getting this error in my text2img function. I understand that Pytorch has recently started supporting m1 GPU. I am getting this error (**RuntimeError: Device type MPS is not supported for torch.Generator() api.**) I put the code below and highlight the line that is giving me the error. Would appreciate any help in getting this to work, thank you!

```
def txt2img(prompt, width, height, guidance_scale, steps, seed): 
  global pipe, pipe_type 

  if pipe_type != 'txt2img': 
    pipe = None 
    clear_memory() 

    pipe_type = 'txt2img' 
    pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained( 
      "CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4", 
      revision="fp16", 
      torch_dtype=torch.float16,
      use_auth_token=YOUR_TOKEN # use huggingface token for private model
    ).to("mps") 

  seed = random.randint(0, 2**32) if seed == -1 else seed 
  generator = torch.Generator(device='mps').manual_seed(int(seed)) 
 
 
  pipe.enable_attention_slicing() 
  with autocast("mps"): 
    image = pipe(prompt=prompt,
                 height=height, width=width,
                 num_inference_steps=steps, guidance_scale=guidance_scale, 
                 generator=generator).images[0] 

  return [[image], seed]
```

The main line of code the error references to is the following: `generator = torch.Generator(device='mps').manual_seed(int(seed))`

Answer (score 2):

Since you only need a random number, just generate it in the CPU instead:

```
generator = torch.Generator().manual_seed(int(seed))
```

Answer (score -1):

I also find this problem. if I use torch.has_mps.manual_seed(SEED), it shows AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'manual_seed'